# zf2 MVCtranslator instead of Translator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to download this module: https://github.com/dphn/ScContent
After succesfully downloading it using composer, I get this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   ScContent\Service\Localization::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator, instance of Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator
>   given, called in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\totaltech\vendor\dphn\sc-content\src\ScContent\Factory\Service\LocalizationFactory.php
>   on line 35 and defined in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\totaltech\vendor\dphn\sc-content\src\ScContent\Service\Localization.php
>   on line 55

What should I do ?

I'm using zf2.3 and skeleton application

Answer (score 1):

The factory used in the skeleton to get the translator is the [TranslatorFactory](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/TranslatorServiceFactory.php) wich return an instance of `Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator`.

The `ScContent\Service\Localization` should use a `Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface` to be able to use both `Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator` and `Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator`.

If i remember well, MvcTranslator was introduced by ZF 2.2.